# Can't view django 2.0 admin page after upgrading

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-middleware, django-upgrade

I've just been porting to Python3 from 2 and upgrading Django from 1.7 to 2.0 (massive changes I know). I'm using Heroku to host the app.

When I run heroku local or just run the app locally with manage.py runserver the app loads but navigating to the /admin page comes up with the error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin
Using the URLconf defined in loowatt.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

write/
admin/
^$ [name='index']
The current path, admin, didn't match any of these.
```

My new app.urls.py looks like this:

```
  1 from django.contrib import admin
  2 from django.urls import include, path
  3
  4 from . import views
  5
  6 urlpatterns = [
  7     path('write/', views.write),
  8     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  9     path('', include('units.urls')),
 10 ]
```

And my settings have all the correct middleware and context processors for the admin settings:

```
 21 INSTALLED_APPS = [
 22     'django.contrib.admin',
 23     'django.contrib.auth',
 24     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 25     'django.contrib.sessions',
 26     'django.contrib.messages',
 27     'units.apps.UnitsConfig',
 28     # Disable Django's own staticfiles handling in favour of WhiteNoise, for
 29     # greater consistency between gunicorn and `./manage.py runserver`. See:
 30     # http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#using-whitenoise-in-development
 31 #    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
 32     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 33     'import_export',
 34     'rangefilter',
 35 ]

 37 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
 38     'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 39     'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 40     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 41     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 42     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 43     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 44     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 45     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 46     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 47 ]

 53 TEMPLATES = [
 54     {
 55         'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
 56         'DIRS': [],
 57         'APP_DIRS': True,
 58         'OPTIONS': {
 59             'context_processors': [
 60                 'django.template.context_processors.debug',
 61                 'django.template.context_processors.request',
 62                 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
 63                 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
 64             ],
 65             'debug': DEBUG,
 66         },
 67     },
 68 ]
```

Anyone have any ideas of what they'd try next to get it working?

Comment: What if you add a tailing slash to the urL?

Comment: Thanks haha I think it may have just been that. I have another error now but that's another story

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't switched from the old-style middleware `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` to the new-style middleware `MIDDLEWARE`. You get the 404 because your project is defaulting to `MIDDLEWARE = []`, so the redirect to append the slash (e.g `/admin` -> `/admin/) isn't happening).

Note that Django 1.7 to 2.0 is a *big* jump. You may find it easier to go via 1.8 and 1.11 (which is LTS and still supported) first. In this case, Django 1.11 supports `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and `MIDDLEWARE`, so you can get your app working on Django 1.11 with `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, switch to `MIDDLEWARE` to fix the deprecation warning, and then you're in a better position to upgrade to Django 2.0.

Note that you can still use `url()` in Django 2.0, so you don't have to rewrite your URL patterns to use `path()` until you've got the rest of the project working.