# Django path() throws 404 when URL ends in Slash

Tags: django, django-urls, django-2.0

Here is urls.py

```
path('about/', about, name='about'),
```

If I visit `/about` it gives 404 error, if if change it to `path('about', about, name='about')`, then if I visit `/about` works but `/about/` gives 404 errors.

What am I doing wrong here, this wasn't not happening prior to Django 2.0

Comment: If you are getting this error after upgrading, then it sounds like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46497561/after-upgrade-to-django-1-11-append-slash-no-longer-works).

Comment: I didn't upgrade to anything, I have clearly mentioned in the question that I'm using Django 2.0 and that question didn't helped me much.

Comment: Yes, I read that you are using Django 2.0. When you say "this wasn't not happening prior to Django 2.0", it looks like you have upgraded Django but did not update your settings. If `/about` does not redirect to `/about/`, that suggests there's a problem with your `MIDDLEWARE` or `APPEND_SLASH` settings. You might find my explanation on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50966180/cant-view-django-2-0-admin-page-after-upgrading/) more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but I don't have enough reputation to do so yet. Anyways, the following might help:

Did you import your views? Because you're referencing the path() wrong. It should be like:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),

]
```

Comment: I didn't show import statement because the question is about a `path`, if you wanna know here my import `from .views import about`

Comment: You say you are using `/about` twice. One time it works, and another time it doesn't... Did you write a typo? Also, you said using `/about/` gives an error... Where are you using that? What is your view/template??